# Second level @import. How to import imported .css files?

Tags: html, css, file, import, composition

I have three .css files: `header.css`, `footer.css` and `breadcrumbs.css`. I imported them all into `compose.css`:

```
@import "/footer/footer.css";
@import "/header/header.css";
@import "breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.css";
```

When I import `compose.css` to `main-page.css` it doesn't import files from `header.css`, `footer.css` and `breadcrumbs.css`, but only from `compose.css`.

Is there any crutchless method to implement the idea of .css double-importing?

Comment: Hello @gleb are you here?

Comment: @MohitGupta, hi, yes. Why are you asking?

Comment: I did same as you asking.. and my css working... so now...  i think your import path should be incorrect.. please check you css path.. which you import in css.. or example me here your css file path.

Comment: @MohitGupta, yeah, the problem was in relative links. I used absolute ones instead

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. The thing is the paths in my compose.css are relative to compose.css itself. And it is evident that these links will not work for main-page.css which is located in another folder. To make it work, i written absolute links. In my case it looks so:

```
@import "http://localhost:63342/labs/php-lab-1/common/default-styles/defaults.css";
@import "http://localhost:63342/labs/php-lab-1/common/footer/footer.css";
@import "http://localhost:63342/labs/php-lab-1/common/header/header.css";
```